# How to execute a process in background by C and use windows API?

Tags: c, windows, process, background

I have a mini program by C for began with windows API. I want to create some processes and run one of them in background and other in foreground by windows API. My code create process:

```
int createBackgroundProcess(){
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.cb = sizeof(si);
CreateProcess("exampleFile.exe",NULL,NULL,NULL,FALSE,
CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi);

WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess,10000);//INFINITE

TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
}
```

How can i make it to background ( Background in there is it still running but we don't see it) (for another process will be run in same time)

Comment: What do you mean by "background"? What type of *behavior* do you want from the process? Are you talking about limiting its priority level?

Comment: Windows has no notion of a "background process".  Any process without a window is pretty background, CREATE_NO_WINDOW is an option.  Other options are creating a service, using the task scheduler, running it on a different desktop.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Background in there is it still running but we don't see it.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yep, I used create_no_window and it's working :D

Comment: You should post that as an answer. In the future, please include more information in your questions about what you're trying to do. Had we known that it was a console application, and you wanted to hide the console window, we could have provided that answer several hours ago without having to guess.

Comment: @CodyGray: tks! I'll edit my question!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `ShowWindow( GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE );`? 
And just make two separate programs, like it would run in the console, and just hide it.